# What is the origin of "have a gander"? (When meaning "look".)

Tags: etymology, phrases, british-english, slang

The phrase "[have a gander](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gander)" meaning "have a look" is common in the UK. (Also can be "have a goosey gander" or just "have a goosey".)

What is the origin/meaning of this phrase? I always assumed that it was Cockney rhyming slang, but I can't think of how it would work as rhyming slang (additionally cockney rhyming slang also has "butcher's" meaning "look", as a rhyme of "butcher's hook").

So why does *have a gander* mean *have a look*?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=gander%20etymology

Comment: @mplungjan that refers to the etymology of the word only. The explanations for the slang term/phrase seem to differ.

Comment: Most of the links on the page have the "crane the neck" in them

Comment: ...and, like most of the "out of the blue" etymologies, they're probably just-so stories. It could just as easily be a dialectical variant of *wander* with some semantic drift thrown in for good measure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With regard to the origin of *gander* in the sense of "take a long look at," it's interesting to compare the definitions of *gonder* in Thomas Darlington, *Folk-Speech of South Cheshire* (1887) with the corresponding definitions in Robert Holland, *A Glossary of Words Used in the County of Cheshire* (1886)—just one year earlier.

From Darlington, [*Folk-Speech*](http://books.google.com/books?id=9XkKAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA206&dq=%22gander+to+stand+at+gaze%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tqcpVMC2MOmmigLP3gE&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22gander%20to%20stand%20at%20gaze%22&f=false) (1887):

> **Gonder**, *v.n.* To stretch the neck like a *gander*, to stand at gaze. "What a't *gonderin'* theer fur?" ... (2) to ramble, walk heedlessly. "Wheer't tha *gonderin'* off to?"

From Holland, [*Glossary*](http://books.google.com/books?id=sFUJAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA145&dq=%22to+ramble+in+conversation%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7agpVIHkDIr7igKI1YCADw&ved=0CDMQ6AEwBDgK#v=onepage&q=%22to%20ramble%20in%20conversation%22&f=false) (1886):

> GONDER, v. (1) to ramble in conversation, to become childish. W. CHES. (2) to go heedlessly. MID-CHES. "Wheer art *gonderin* to?"

So while Darlington and Holland agree as to the sense "walk or go heedlessly," they have quite different alternative meanings for the verb *gonder*.

Roger Wilbraham, [*An Attempt at a Glossary of Some Words Used in Cheshire*](http://books.google.com/books?id=Fh9JAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA101&dq=%22gander-month%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LawpVIX8AsPUiwLU1YHwBw&ved=0CFIQ6AEwCTgU#v=onepage&q=%22gander-month%22&f=false), second edition (1826), published 60 years earlier, doesn't include an entry for *gonder* (or *gander*) at all, although it does have one for *gander-month*:

> GANDER-MONTH, s. the month in which a man's wife is confined in lying in.

Egerton Leigh, [*A Glossary of Words Used in the Dialect of Cheshire*](http://books.google.com/books?id=F-wIAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA91&dq=gonder+gooseberry&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3a0pVOLpLeOBiwKIpIGIDg&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=gonder%20gooseberry&f=false) (1877) essentially repeats Wilbraham's wording for *gander-month* and adds two entries for *gonder*:

> GONDER, s.—A gooseberry. L.
>
> GONDER s.—A gander. Also, a fool, "What a gonder thee art, Raphe!" L.

—but no verb forms of *gonder*.

Meanwhile, Georgina Jackson, [*Shropshire Word-book*](http://books.google.com/books?id=BzoLAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA180&dq=gonder+gooseberry&hl=en&sa=X&ei=M64pVOSYHoLJigLesoCYCw&ved=0CDYQ6AEwBjgU#v=onepage&q=gonder%20gooseberry&f=false) (1879) has this meaning of *gonder* as a verb:

> **GONDER** (2) v. n. to mope about.—PULVERBATCH [near Shrewsbury] 'That fellow's good fur nuthin' but gonder about like a kimet ship ["dizzy sheep"].'

Also of interest is a discussion by "W. J. C." in [Manchester] [City News Notes and Queries](http://books.google.com/books?id=mvEHAAAAQAAJ&pg=RA1-PA37&dq=gondering+to+wander+heedlessly&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EbUpVIz4BOj-igKe74CABg&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=gondering%20to%20wander%20heedlessly&f=false) (March 5, 1881) of the meaning of *gondering* in South Cheshire and of differences between that district of Cheshire and the district north of it:

> I fear MID-CHESHIRE [a correspondent to the newspaper] did not read my communication of the 12th with care, or he would have noticed that I stated distinctly the particular district in which the words I gave are used. I must therefore beg to state again that South Cheshire is the district to which I referred, and he writes from Mid-Cheshire. Now it is well known that dialect words are used in one part of a county that are never heard in another part. ... "Gondering," to wander heedlessly, is used with the same meaning in South Cheshire [as in Mid-Cheshire]; and "gonder," a noun, is applied to person, and signifies one who does not mind where he is going.

Thus, seven years before Darlington finds *gonder* being used in South Cheshire to mean "stretch the neck like a gander" and "stand at gaze," W. J. C. of South Cheshire, in discussing *gondering*, indicates no awareness of that usage.

But lest it appear that South Cheshire's *gondering* is a dead end on the road to "take a gander," Joseph Wright, [The English Dialect Dictionary](http://books.google.com/books?id=7Ks4AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA553&dq=%22to+stretch+the+neck+like+a+gander%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=q74pVP2LA4LJigLesoCYCw&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22to%20stretch%20the%20neck%20like%20a%20gander%22&f=false) (1900) cites the Darlington definition as part of a longer subdefinition of *gander*:

> **7.** To stretch the neck like a gander, to stand gazing, look foolish ; to use conceited airs and gestures.

Wright also cites a much earlier instance of a similar usage of the word, albeit one involving a different variant spelling: *gaindering*. The citation is to James Hogg, [*The Three Perils of Man*](http://books.google.com/books?id=yrkBAAAAQAAJ&pg=RA2-PA202&dq=gaindering&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HbspVP-_GobwiwL_zoGoDw&ved=0CDYQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=gaindering&f=false) (1822), a novel set on the Scottish/English border, which includes this dialogue:

> "Poor tafferel ruined tawpies! What are ye gaun **gaindering** about that gate for, as ye didna ken whilk end o' ye were uppermost?"
>
> "That's easily kend father. What has come ower ye? Hae ye seen a warlock that ye are gaping and glowring at sic a dismal rate?"

In this scene, a farmer has spotted a band of border rovers descending on his farmhouse, and he has rushed back to the house, where his daughters, surprised at his unexplained franticness, are not wandering about aimlessly but staring out the door.

The complication here is pointed out by John Jamieson, [*Supplement to the Etymological Dictionary of the Scottish Language*](http://books.google.com/books?id=Vj1CAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA455&dq=%22to+gainder%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wcIpVObBJsr3oATjhoHYBQ&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22to%20gainder%22&f=false), volume 1 (1825):

> To GAINDER, (*g* hard), *v. n.*  To look foolish, *Ettr. For*. [Hogg quotation omitted] Supposed to signify, to look like a *gander*. But it is perhaps originally the same with GAINTER, q. v.
>
> ...
>
> To GAINTER, v. n. To use conceited airs and gestures ; Gainterin', having the appearance of assuming conceited airs; Upp. Clydes.

Still, from the context of the Hogg quotation, it's fairly clear that the farmer's daughters have not gone to the gate conceitedly, but out of curiosity and alarm—and possibly with their necks craned. If so, the origin of *gander* in the sense of "stretching one's neck like a goose in order to stare at something" may be traced (as *gainder*) to 1822—sixty-five years before the South Cheshire origin (as *gonder*) cited by the Online Etymology Dictionary—unless (as is possible) Hogg's farmer meant *gaindering* in the sense of "wandering foolishly," a sense of the verb *gander* that the Online Etymology Dictionary dates to the 1680s. Wright, at any rate, doesn't attribute the "wandering foolishly" sense to *gaindering* in Hogg's dialogue.

Comment: Thank you for this complete answer. Am I the only one that finds appreciation (and humor) in the title "An Attempt at a Glossary of Some Words Used in Cheshire"? Talk about the opposite of bombastic titles: it's restricted to CHESHIRE; and it's not ALL words, just SOME; and even at that, it's just an ATTEMPT.

Comment: This title reminds me of that of a book on my shelves _Navajo made Easier_.

Answer (score 7):

The way geese move their neck to look around seems to be at the origin of this saying:

[gander](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gander): from Etymonline.com

> - "take a long look," slang, 1886, from gander (n.) on the notion of craning one's neck like a goose; earlier it meant "to wander foolishly" (1680s). Related: Gandered; gandering.

[Gander](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-gan2.htm) from (www.worldwidewords.org)

> - A quick, er, gander at the word’s history is illuminating. It seems the verb to gander in this sense is actually American in origin, something I find more than a little surprising, because it sounds English to me. A little more delving, however, shows that the roots of the expression are indeed from this side of the pond. **A work of 1887, The Folk-Speech of South Cheshire, says, “Gonder, to stretch the neck like a gander, to stand at gaze”. The next known example is from the Cincinnati Enquirer of 9 May 1903: “Gander, to stretch or rubber your neck”. It is claimed that it comes from thieves’ slang.**
> - Think of a gaggle of farmyard geese, wandering about in their typically aimless and stupid way, poking their noses in everywhere and twisting their necks to stare at anything that might be interesting. Geese are the archetypal rubberneckers. No doubt to gander became the term because to goose had already been borrowed; this was taken from the way that the birds were known to put their beaks embarrassingly — and sometimes painfully — into one’s more private places.
> - to take a gander, is recorded from the USA around 1914; here, gander is a noun in the sense of a inquisitive look. In the century since, that form has become much more common while the verb has lost ground.

Answer (score 0):

It's Cockney rhyming slang. "Goose and Duck" became "Gander and Duck" = look. See also the nursery rhyme "Goosey Goosey Gander" which is where the " wander" association comes from.

> "Goose" still has a sexual meaning in British culture, and that the nursery rhyme preserves these sexual overtones ("In my lady's chamber").
>   <sub>[Wikipedia: Goosey Goosey Gander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goosey_Goosey_Gander)</sub>

Which is why "goose" was dropped and "Gander" became the shortened version.

Comment: Welcome to SE. If you had followed the guided tour you would be aware that we are only interested in answers supported by citations. Unfortunately you provide no evidence that gander is derived from Cockney rhyming slang via "goose" (most dictionaries give a different origin), no reference to the sexual connotations of "my lady's chamber" in the nursery rhyme (the Wikipedia reference says nothing about this), and no indication of how old the sexual meaning of "goose" is — my impression is that it is fairly restricted and recent.That is why someone has voted you down.

Comment: Look up "Goosey Goosey Gander" in wiki. : 
Other interpretations exist. Mark Cocker and Richard Mabey note in Birds Britannica that the greylag goose has for millennia been associated with fertility, that "goose" still has a sexual meaning in British culture, and that the nursery rhyme preserves these sexual overtones ("In my lady's chamber"

Comment: Look up Goosey Goosey Gander in Wikipedia and see: Mark Cocker and Richard Mabey note in Birds Britannica that the greylag goose has for millennia been associated with fertility, that "goose" still has a sexual meaning in British culture, and that the nursery rhyme preserves these sexual overtones ("In my lady's chamber")

Comment: "Unfortunately you provide no evidence that gander is derived from Cockney rhyming slang via "goose" (most dictionaries give a different origin)  This is folk etymology (told to me by my Grandfather b1894 d1967) and as such is not comprehensively written down. As for dictionaries they all usually just copy one another with no research of their own.

Comment: Please re-read the first two sentences of my comment. As you are a first-poster I was trying to help you by explaining how the list worked. In saying you provided no evidence I was not saying that you were wrong, only that your answer gave neither me nor the OP any basis on which to judge whether you were right or wrong. It is frustrating when you are convinced something is so (I was certainly frustrated when I started) but that is the way this list works. If Mark Cocker and Richard Mabey support you then you should say so — with citation — in your answer.

Comment: Just look at some of the pretentious twaddle above: Gonder, Gainter ,long-necked cranes and machinery cranes etc. These posters are just fitting together rather specious ideas to make up a theory. I am reminded of all the authors who have "proved" that at least 200 other people wrote the works of Shakespeare.

Comment: Let me explain further. List members who have accumulated a ‘reputation’ of 3000 are able — and encouraged — to perform certain review tasks. (SE is self-governing within an overall framework.) These include reviewing first posts from new users, with the instructions “Help them learn to use the site by reviewing their post”. That is what brought me to your answer, rather than the question, which doesn’t particularly interest me. Regarding other posts, the idea is that the voting system will sort the wheat from the chaff,  and with enough reputation one can comment to point out factual errors.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by :Regarding other posts, the idea is that the voting system will sort the wheat from the chaff, and with enough reputation one can comment to point out factual errors. – David Jul 8 at 8:37

Comment: Oxford/Cambridge/London produced dictionaries only show the usage from the very narrow band of geographical/academic areas in which they exist and all copy each other. And they show only a very small percentage of what was really the vernacular in most of the country. The English language was NOT handed down to us on tablets of stone. It is made up as we go along and no person or institution can dictate to the people what they can or not say.

Comment: By "Regarding other posts..." I was responding to your remark "Just look at some of the pretentious twaddle above". I meant that whether or not other posts are "twaddle" — as you claim — is irrelevant to criticism of your post because the system I described will deal with the other posts. It may not give the "truth", but no system is perfect, and I was describing how this system operated, for good or bad, to you as a new poster.

Comment: I assume your remark about British dictionaries is related to my initial comment in which I cited dictionaries as not giving the answer you did, in the absence of any evidence you had provided at the time. I am happy to see that you have now responded to my comment and provided evidence from another Wikipedia page. Obviously,  dictionaries are not the only source of information on the English language and the history of its usage. Whether or not I am convinced by your explanation I will up vote your answer now.

Answer (score -1):

I expect it just alludes to geese having long necks, making it really obvious when a gander

> [**cranes<sup>1</sup> its neck**](http://www.chacha.com/question/what-does-it-mean-to-crane-ones-neck)
>    *reach forward with head and neck, in order to see better*

---

<sup>1</sup> I didn't know until I just looked it up, but the etymology for the above verb *and* the noun *crane = machine for raising and lowering heavy weights* both derive from *crane = **long-necked** bird (of the family Gruidæ)*.

Comment: It would be nice to have something more than “expectation” for the this, and why you see a connection between the word ‘gander’ and ‘crane’.

Comment: @David: The problem with this particular usage is that all the "easy" research will just turn up stuff dating back well over a century, for what was originally an *American* slang usage. But compare BrE/AmE corpuses in [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+a+gander&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20gander%3B%2Cc0), which clearly shows a *massive* uptake in recent decades - more marked in BrE, but with a smaller upswing in AmE caused by exposure to wider dialectal usage as a result of cultural mixing during WW2.